# User Session in Angular4

Tags: angular, authentication, usersession

so i m making an online library app with angular !the user must log in every time he would like to buy a new item 
SO i m searching for a method that allowed me to store the user session in order to skip the authentication step every time he would liketo buy a new item

Any ideas ? 
thanks

Comment: use localStorage if you want to store the user session always or a service to save this user session. Remember that a services are living along all the live of the application

Comment: You could use ngrx-store and combine it with ngrx-store-localstorage to persist your state on pagerefreshes: https://github.com/ngrx/platform and https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage